# How to move your code in codeskulptor from the browser to python 2.7?

Tags: python, ide

I am learning a course on Coursera: "An Introduction to Interactive Programming in Python".

I have written the whole of the code in the course in the browser and I have used a library called `simplegui` for all the GUI functionality.

I want to move this over to IDLE and then edit and work on it from there.

(I am also thinking of freezing the repository and then distributing it)

Comment: Me comes from the course too :) Very interested in this, nice thread!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download this github repository.

[simplegui tk Library](https://github.com/IcyFlame/simpleguitk)

And then place the file with the CodeSkulptor code inside a `.py` file and add the line at the beginning of the code:

`import simpleguitk as simplegui`

And then you are all set to run this application. For most of the time, It works fine.

I have not yet checked it with sounds and images but I think you can get it to work with images too, in case it does not.

I thank the author of this library: GitHub User dholm for the amazing functionality he has given us.

Answer (score -2):

First download the simplegui tk library as suggested above after that you also have to install a python3-tk package by using the command:

```
sudo-apt get install python3-tk
```

package after which you will easily able to run the program without using code sculptor.